# How to convert millisecond time stamp to normal date in Python?

Tags: python, timestamp, milliseconds

I have a data frame with a column with values in millisecond time stamp.(`df['Millisecond']`)

What I want to do is to convert all values of that column into normal dates. Ex. 2017-04-27 04:55:00

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can do this by using to_datetime function https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html.

```
df['Millisecond'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Millisecond'], unit='ms')
```

Answer (score 25):

You need python's datetime package to do that:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(milliseconds/1000.0)

date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: I used the other answer because it was much easier but this one works aswell. Thanks :)

Comment: @R.Trading, but this answer is more efficient than other one, as in that answer pandas is being used that is not necessary for just conversion. thanks.